# Remove duplicated string(s) in strings in a list

Tags: python, string, list

a need to remove some duplicates.

A list contains elements, which are strings contains strings separated by “;”. The strings in each string could be duplicated. Such as:

```
"15-105;ZH0311;TZZGJJ; ZH0311; ZH0311;DOC",
```

There are 3 “ZH0311” in the string (the number of appearing is not fixed). I need to eliminate the duplicates and refine the string to (sequence of strings inside doesn't matter):

```
"15-105;TZZGJJ; ZH0311;DOC",
```

I am thinking to split the strings by ";" and link them together. How can I do the same for the whole list?

```
a_list = [

"15~105;~ PO185-400CT;NGG;DOC",
"15~105;-1;NGG;DOC",
"15~105; 15~105; NGG;-10;NGG;DOC",
"15~55;J205~J208;POI;DOC",
"15-105;15-105;ZH0305~;WER /;TZZGJJ;DOC",
"15-105;ZH0311;TZZGJJ; ZH0311; ZH0311;DOC",
"15-115;15-115; PL026~ PL028; Dry;PTT"]
```

**please note the strings contains Non-ASCII characters.**

By the way question:
Is it a difference that it’s not strings in the list, but lists in the list and elements in each nested list are duplicated?

Comment: thanks, figs. because the original strings contains Non-ASCII characters. Seems "set" doesn't produce needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = "15-105;ZH0311;TZZGJJ; ZH0311; ZH0311;DOC"
>>> a = map(str.strip,a.split(';'))
>>> a
['15-105', 'ZH0311', 'TZZGJJ', 'ZH0311', 'ZH0311', 'DOC']
>>> a = sorted(set(a),key=lambda x:a.index(x))
>>> a
['15-105', 'ZH0311', 'TZZGJJ', 'DOC']
>>> ";".join(a)
'15-105;ZH0311;TZZGJJ;DOC'
```

i have used split to split it  then strip to remove extra spaces. I have use set to remove duplication, but set dosent care about order. so i need to sort in the order as they are

```
>>> def remove_duplication(my_list):
...     my_newlist = []
...     for x in my_list:
...         x = map(str.strip,x.split(';'))
...         my_newlist.append(";".join(sorted(set(x),key=lambda y:x.index(y))))
...     return my_newlist
... 
>>> remove_duplication(a_list)
['15~105;~ PO185-400CT;NGG;DOC', '15~105;-1;NGG;DOC', '15~105;NGG;-10;DOC', '15~55;J205~J208;POI;DOC', '15-105;ZH0305~;WER /;TZZGJJ;DOC', '15-105;ZH0311;TZZGJJ;DOC', '15-115;PL026~ PL028;Dry;PTT']
```

if your string is delimited by space:

```
>>> a="# -- coding: utf-8 --" 
>>> a= map(str.strip,a.split())
>>> a
['#', '--', 'coding:', 'utf-8', '--']
>>> a = " ".join(sorted(set(a),key=lambda x:a.index(x)))
>>> a
'# -- coding: utf-8'
```

`split` split the string on some delimiter, it may be space punchuatation or character or can be anything.

Go though all this documentation, you will understand. [Built-in types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), 
[Built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Comment: Ooh you're right about mapping to `str.strip`. Your answer is better -- deleted mine. However OP mentions that order doesn't matter so you don't have to sort your set.

Comment: thanks, Hackaholic. it runs fine. however for the Non-ASCII characters in the strings, it doesn't display well when I print them. is there a way?

Comment: thanks again. i give "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" on the first line but it still the same...

Comment: `#; --; coding:; utf-8; --` if you give input delimited by ';' then it will work as in your post its delimited by ';'

Comment: sorry Hackaholic, but I still don't understand. would it be possible you put it in your updated answer? thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65331/discussion-between-mark-k-and-hackaholic).

Comment: Hackaholic's very very helpful, patient, handsome and sexy.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all the strings into a set after stripping them like so:

```
def myFilter(lines):
    strings = []
    for curLine in lines:
        strings.extend([curString.strip() for curString in curLine.split(";")])
    return set(strings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` and `set`

```
>>> s = "15-105;ZH0311;TZZGJJ; ZH0311; ZH0311;DOC"
>>> ';'.join(s.split(";"))
'15-105;ZH0311;TZZGJJ; ZH0311; ZH0311;DOC'
>>>
```